# Retrieve $_POST variable from array name

Tags: php, post

Consider the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="random[variable][here]" value="valueofrandom"/>
```

Is there a better way to retrieve its value if we have the name as a string? The following works, but it doesn't seem very *smart*.

```
function getPostValueFromName($name) {
    // Example string name: random[variable][here]
    $parts = preg_split('/\[|\]/i', $name, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    if (isset($parts[3])) {
        return $_POST[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2][$parts[3]]];
    } elseif (isset($parts[2])) {
        return $_POST[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]];
    } elseif (isset($parts[1])) {
        return $_POST[$parts[0]][$parts[1]];
    } else {
        return $_POST[$parts[0]];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1. make your function recursive. 2. if you dont care about the array keys, why use them in the first place?

Comment: I must be missing something simple. How would you build it recursively as a `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0):

I use **https://github.com/symfony/PropertyAccess** for things like this.

Using it, you can get `random[variable][here]` with

```
$accessor = new PropertyAccessor();

$val = $accessor->getValue($_POST, 'random.variable.here');
// or
$val = $accessor->getValue($_POST, 'random[variable][here]');
```

Comment: Prefer to do without needing symfony.

Comment: Symfony is not needed. PropertyAccess can be used as a standalone